# Center table - colour either side

Tags: html, css

Trying to fix something for an email. Screenshot of problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d6sh.jpg

There is basically a 600width table that I need the same background color and text color as the rest of the email.

Yet as you see either side is white - what do I do here? Make two tables to the left and right? And make them grey or can I make the text stay like it is and make the table width 100%? Because that skews my text formatting.

Any help greatly appreciated - here is my code (couldnt format properly with 4 spacing so used backquotes:

```
<table width="600" height="21" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background-color:#ccc;font-family:verdana; font-size:10px; color:FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#000000; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <font style="font-family:arial;font-size:10px;">
              You have received this email from an independent marketing company x x x x x x x .Company Reg. No.03976500 You have registered to receive our email advertising from one of our sites, and may unsubscribe from this newsletter by clicking <a href="">here</a><br> For more information on how we use your data, please read our <a href="http:/www.yoy.co.uk/privacy-legal" style="color: #5B5B5B;" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>.
            </font> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Cheers

Comment: Just add this css - `body:background-color:#123456;`

Comment: Thank youuu - can you put that in an answer so I can give you the points?

Comment: Yeah, just posted it.

Comment: Oh, and by "add this css" I mean add it as an inline style. Works best that way for emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this css - body:background-color:#123456;

Answer (score 0):

Just use a div tag and some special CSS classes.

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc;font-family:arial;font-size:10px;">
  <table style="width: 600px;margin:0 auto;font-family:verdana;color:FFFFFF;">...</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes this method doesn't work in emails. It's safer to add inline styles.

Comment: css classes in emails is a bad idea, you should only use style attributes for full cross client support!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#000000; color:#fff; width:100%">
    <div style="width:600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;">
              You have received this email from an independent marketing company x x x x x x x .Company Reg. No.03976500 You have registered to receive our email advertising from one of our sites, and may unsubscribe from this newsletter by clicking <a href="">here</a><br> For more information on how we use your data, please read our <a href="http:/www.yoy.co.uk/privacy-legal" style="color: #5B5B5B;" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```